# Prompt for Array Size For Input

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, input

My program executes as I desire it to, however I wish to modify the scanner such that the user can specify the length of the array they are inputting. So when the program launches it will ask how many numbers. Then it will follow through with its execution of printing the numbers in order and then in reverse order. Here is my current program. What would I need to modify to allow this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment01b {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        int[] numbers=new int[6];
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter elements...");
        for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
            numbers[j]=sc.nextInt();

         if (printOriginalArray(numbers) != 0)
             System.out.println("ERROR!");

         if (printInReverse(numbers) != 0)
             System.out.println("ERROR!");

         System.out.println("\nProgram completed successfully!");

    }

    public static int printOriginalArray(int[] list) {

        System.out.println("The list in order is: ");

         for (int num: list)
         System.out.print(num + " ");

         return 0;

    }

    public static int printInReverse(int[] list) {

        System.out.println("\nThe list in reverse order is:");

        for (int i = list.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
        }

        return 0;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this Follow code snippet

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] numbers = new int[sc.nextInt()];
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the following changes.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {


    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter no of elements...");
    int noOfElements = sc.nextInt();
    int[] numbers=new int[noOfElements];
    System.out.println("Please enter elements...");
    for(int j=0;j<noOfElements;j++)
        numbers[j]=sc.nextInt();

     if (printOriginalArray(numbers) != 0)
         System.out.println("ERROR!");

     if (printInReverse(numbers) != 0)
         System.out.println("ERROR!");

     System.out.println("\nProgram completed successfully!");

}
```